Android 13/14 - How to replace a system app with an older version?
I need to "downgrade" the google app with an older version because of a voice typing issue.  However, the older version gets uninstalled after reboot.  I have explicitly uninstall the original one then install the one I want, but after reboot, it's reverted back.  I Know system app can be restored, thus an apk is probably resides in the system image partition.
If I only disable/uninstall the google app, then it stays "gone" after reboot.  So I need to disable the auto-update on system app if possible.  Or replace the original with the older version in the corresponding partitions.
